# K2 extension: Social media (particularly Facebook) button with articles not working properly

Tags: k2

Facebook button that comes by default with K2 extension under articles is not working properly. When Facebook button is clicked, the menu does not open to full length so that one can press post button (For instance, see this article http://www.sdsolutions.firm.in/business-management/item/28-4-things-to-define-in-project-report-when-it-comes-to-value-creation).

Comment: Hi. If something is not working properly in a 3rd party extension, I recommend you contact the developer as there's nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

From your template.css file on line 5725 you can easliy solve this problem by modifying the css to **max-width: inherit;** instead of the current one **max-width: 100%;** Hope this helps.

Comment: Did max-width: inherit; but problem remains. .

Comment: I am not sure what you wanted. From my end i can see the like like/share button is working quite fine. Therefore i will assume that my solution solved your issue. Make sure you have cleared the cookies and your browser cache before trying to load your site again. And if it is solved please mark the answer as correct to help any other person who might have be facing the same issue

Comment: I'm afraid this is what the output is once I login with my Facebook id: http://splendidjoomla.blogspot.in/2015/12/stack-exchange-query-regarding-facebook.html

Comment: And this is what i can see on my end check this out http://signaturejournal.org/mobile_learning/uploads/28578-facebook.png

Comment: Thanks, the issue is sorted by your tip. Maybe earlier there was a problem related with cache.